# message.channel.send only sends the first array and nothing else

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command where it generates a random moth, with a randomly chosen name, gender identity, moth type, and favorite food. For some reason it only sends a letter from the first array `LS1`. My current code is here:

```
  client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content === "mof:create") {
      const LS1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
      const LS2 = ["i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]
      const LS3 = ["r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
      const GENDERID = ["male ", "female ", "non-binary "]
      const MOTHTYPE = ["rosy maple ", "silkworm ", "luna ", "pink luna ", "stained glass ", "death's head hawk "]
      const FOODLIST = ["sugar water", "honey", "apples", "watermelon", "strawberries", "blueberries"]
      const CP1 = LS1[Math.floor(Math.random() * LS1.length)];
      const CP2 = LS2[Math.floor(Math.random() * LS2.length)];
      const CP3 = LS3[Math.floor(Math.random() * LS3.length)];
      const GID = GENDERID[Math.floor(Math.random() * GENDERID.length)];
      const MTP = MOTHTYPE[Math.floor(Math.random() * MOTHTYPE.length)];
      const SGF = FOODLIST[Math.floor(Math.random() * FOODLIST.length)];
          message.channel.send(CP1, CP2, CP3, " is a ", GID, MTP, "moth that likes to mostly eat ", SGF);
  }
});
```

Here is the current output I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using + instead of, in
message.channel.send(CP1, CP2, CP3, " is a ", GID, MTP, "moth that likes to mostly eat ", SGF);

You should concatenate the string by using CP1+CP2+...